# How do I keep a Kubernetes pod running with no http endpoint? (prevent back-off)

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I have a usecase where (at least for now) I need a k8s pod to stay up without a HTTP or TCP endpoint. I tried the following deployment...

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: node-deployment
  labels:
    app: node-app
spec: 
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: node-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-server
        image: node:17-alpine
        exec:
            command: ["node","-v"]
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["node","-v"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5  
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["node","-v"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
```

But after a while it stops the pod with the following error...

> Warning  BackOff    5s (x10 over 73s)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container

And the pod status shows...

> node-deployment-58445f5649-z6lkz           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (103s ago)   4m47s

I know it is running because I see the version in `kubectl logs <node-name>`. How do I get the image to stay up with no long running process? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

The process of the container simply exited, the same happens if you run `node -v` in your terminal.

Not sure if the use case you provide is your real use case ( I can't see any reason to have the node version as an application), so ..

if you really want to have the version, you can change the command to be

```
["watch","-n1","node","-v"]
```

So it will print the node version every second

Comment: Is it looking to see that there are no processes running and shutting down the container or is it more complicated?

Comment: `watch` is a process that will not exit if there are no errors

Comment: [here](https://www.tutorialworks.com/why-containers-stop/#:~:text=The%20main%20process%20inside%20the,script%20to%20perform%20some%20tasks.) is a good description

Comment: A container only runs one process, and if that process exits, the container finishes too.  A Kubernetes Pod usually only contains a single container; so if the process exits, the Pod stops, and by default they will get restarted.  But in the basic case it's nothing more complex than "the single process in the container stopped".